# Successful PP payment but originating website down

Tags: php, timeout

Over the years this has happened a couple of times:

1. User checks out with PP and is sent to PP to log in.
2. Pre-auth ok. Returns to our website.
3. User selects shipping method and authorizes
4. Sent to PP for authorization and order is confirmed with PP
5. Our web server momentarily down or timed out when PP redirects to it. Record/sale is not completed at our website.

Any tips or ideas on how to avoid this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Add the record for the sale prior to attempting step 4 then update it with the outcome.

You would then be able to identify successes, fails and no responses.

To keep thinks tidy you might want to delete the orders that return with a failed response. This way for the items in an indeterminate state you will have the information needed to fulfill the order once someone confirms payment.